# Error while creation of tables in the selected database in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error as `A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/Test.php on line 25` and `mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user 'pass'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/Test.php on line 25` when i trying to create a tables in a created Data base.

My code:

```
  <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass");
    connection to mysql server
    //checking the connection
     if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
        echo "Sorry!Failed to connect Mysql" . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
      $sql = "CREATE DATABASE viral_coff";
     if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
     echo "database Created Successfully!";
     else
     echo "error in creating the database" . mysqli_error($con);
     mysql_select_db('viral_coff') or die(mysql_error());;
     $tab = ' CREATE TABLE retention( '.
            ' playing-date DATE ,' .
            ' that-day INT ,' .
            ' 1_day INT ,' .
            ' 3_days INT ,' .
            ' 7_days INT ,' .
            ' 31_days INT ,)' ; 
     if(mysqli_query($con,$tab))
     echo "Created Tables";
     else
     echo "Error creating table" . mysqli_error($con); 
     mysqli_close($con)
    ?>
```

What am i  doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` functions. *Which you of course can't!*

You need to use `mysqli_select_db()` instead of `mysql_select_db()`

Also learn to put some brackets on your if statements, thereby you can be 100% sure of what is inside and outside of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_ and mysqli_ functions dont work well together. Choose one of it and work with them, not both.

Answer (score 0):

**You are remove password.**

```
<?php
define('Hostname','localhost');
define('Username','root');
define('Password','');
define('DB_Name','viral_coff');

$con=mysqli_connect(Hostname,Username,Password);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE ".DB_Name;
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Database ".DB_Name." created successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

$con = mysqli_connect(Hostname,Username,Password,DB_Name);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE retention(playing_date DATE, that_day INT, 1_day INT , 3_days INT ,7_days INT , 31_days INT)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Table retention created successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```